# Words Changing on an App

Tags: android

I am wondering if for example I have a "Hello World" Android app and decide to put it on the play store. If I changed the words to "Goodbye World", would it change on someone phone who already had it downloaded when it said "Hello World"? Or would they need to update their app?

Comment: Please use fire-base it may be solve your problem.

Comment: If you hardcode the word in the app then user have to upgrade the app. If you want to change the word without user having to upgrade the app, try to fetch the words from a server via http calls. Firebase is a good choice for this

Comment: you need to specify which way you want to change words.Define your question properly.

Comment: Yes, you can change it using Api & no need to update your app on playstore.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Firebase Remote 
Config**

Remote config allows you update your app without necessarily deploying a new version of your app.

Sample tutorial

https://segunfamisa.com/posts/firebase-remote-config

Official tutorial

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/